# Building REACT Project Error Message (Entrypoint html-webpack-plugin for "index.html" = index.html)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm unable to build my react project using `npm run build` as I keep getting the error message below:

```
Child __offline_serviceworker:
     1 asset
    Entrypoint __offline_serviceworker = __offline_serviceworker
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint html-webpack-plugin for "index.html" = index.html
```

I'm fairly new to building react projects so apologies if this is an amateur question. What I've tried already:

1. I've tried changing the entry point by following this [html-webpack-plugin Entrypoint undefined = index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841918/html-webpack-plugin-entrypoint-undefined-index-html) but it still hasn't worked.
2. I've attempted downgrading webpack to `3.07` as well but that solution didn't help either.
3. I've tried other options including `npm i mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony` in terminal as pointed out here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-pwa/issues/7 but still no luck

I currently can't think of any other solution thus I decided to post here.

My webpack is located in: `internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel`

My `index.html` is located in the root folder

In my package.json, I have webpack as follows:

```
"devDependencies": {
 "html-webpack-plugin": "3.0.7",
...
}
```

I'd totally appreciate help to help resolve this issue. Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run build` will work only if you specify what needs to be done for build in the package.json file.
but if your intension is just to install packages(i.e. first step) run "`npm install`" and to run the code run "`npm start`"

Comment: my intention is to deploy the app via FTP. Does, I'm doing npm run build to get a build of the app first then deploy it. Yet I keep running into the above error :(